# Python 2 to 3 "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Tags: python

I am trying to convert code from Python version 2 to 3.

**Error**: "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str"

**Code** used is:

```
    file = sys.argv[1]
    if os.path.exists(file):
        with open(file,'r') as inputFile:
            i = 0
            output = BytesIO()
            for line in inputFile.readlines():
                if (re.search("^[0-9]+\.",line)):
                    i += 1
                    replacement = str(i)+'. '
                    newLine = re.sub('^[0-9]+\.\s*(\[?[0-9]*\]?\s*)*',replacement,line)
                    output.write(newLine)
                else:
                    output.write(line)

            print ("Number of steps:", i)

        with open(file,'w') as inputFile:
            inputFile.write(output.getvalue())
```

I realise that the error has to do with the type of the object, but I don't understand how to fix the issue. I would appreciate any guidance. Thank you.

Comment: Why not use StringIO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BytesIO` expects bytes. So when you do `output.write(x)`, you need `x` to be of type bytes. The problem is that both `line` and `newLine` are of type string.

You could convert them to bytes by encoding them, but since you're trying to write `output` to a file, the best solution would actually be to change `BytesIO` for `StringIO`. The latter will not complain for `line` and `newLine` being strings, and you'll be able to call `inputFile.write(output.getvalue())`, which is only possible if output is a `StringIO`.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to encode the string to bytes, e.g.: `bytes_like = some_string.encode('utf-8')` and now it should work, then if you need a string, decode your bytes, e.g `string_type = some_bytes.decode('utf-8')`.